# Ransack gem - Case insensitive sort (Rails 4)

Tags: sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

Using the Ransack gem, I'm trying to sort a simple list on an index page. However, there are both uppercase and lowercase values in the sort field `name`. To make them sorted useful, the sort should be case insensitive.

This is the model `Vendor`:

```
name:string, email:string, address:string, phone:string, fax:string
```

This is the controller:

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @search = Vendor.search(params[:q])
  @vendors = @search.result
end
```

And the view:

```
/index.html.slim
tr
  th = sort_link @search, :name, "Name"
  th = sort_link @search, :email, "Company Email"
  th = sort_link @search, :address, "Address"
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `sorted_list = vendors.sort {|a,b| a.name.downcase <=> b.name.downcase}` # try that and let me know if it helps

Comment: @hd1 thanks for the quick reply! would you please give me a little more though? I tried placing this in the controller's search and result, but no luck. Still a newb.

Comment: Try adding an accessor to your model that returns name as lowercase and searching on that field? `def lowercase_name name.downcase! end` and configure ransack to search the lowercase_name field using @search.sorts in your [controller](http://techbrownbags.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/rails-ajax-search-sort-paginate-with-ransack-kaminari/)

Comment: Did try but this poses another challenge for someone at my level. Getting values of a virtual attribute is straight forward but using it to sort seems to require a bit of a hack. Please share with me some code if there's a good way to accomplish this... Thanks again.

Comment: @hd1, thanks to your first suggestion, I got it at least work... adding answer so that there's code to see...

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking for is a custom "Ransacker":

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base

    ransacker :name_case_insensitive, type: :string do
      arel_table[:name].lower
    end

end
```

view:

```
th = sort_link(@q, :name_case_insensitive)
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what this does or how it works? I am specifically confused about the use of 'arel_table'.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this for all string columns of a model at once by using this approach:

```
# lib/ransack_object.rb

module RansackObject

  def self.included(base)
    base.columns.each do |column|
      if column.type == :string
        base.ransacker column.name.to_sym, type: :string do
          Arel.sql("lower(#{base.table_name}.#{column.name})")
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Then include the ransack object in your model:

```
class UserWithManyAttributes < ActiveRecord::Base

  include RansackObject

end
```

Comment: This takes care of downcasing the database side, but not the search term. This works if the search term is already in lower case.

Comment: I would like to ask a question, I am sending `"q"=>{"s"=>"price asc"}` from frontside and in my query it does `ORDER BY "products"."price" ASC` automatically. Is this due to above code? I have codebase from someone else who has this code in it but I cant figureout the reason of it how its appending `ORDER BY "products"."price" ASC` based on condition. Same goes from price desc etc or even by title asc desc etc. Can you please help and explain the reason. Thanks.!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used Rails ans Ransack for a few years now. But it sounds very likely that sending this condition to Ransack will result in the matching query.

Comment: This works great in 2024, and is now the preferred way to do this according to the [ransack documentation](https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/getting-started/simple-mode/#case-insensitive-sorting-in-postgresql). Also worth noting that you may need to add if column.type == :string || column.type == :text if you are using Postgres and text data types for this to work correctly on those columns.

Comment: I feel honored to be part of the docs now! Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 2):

Ransack now has a `case_insensitive` option
you can custom a predicate with `case_insensitive: false`

Refrences: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Custom-Predicates

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but I'm not understanding how one would construct a predicate to be used with a sort_link. The [official ransack documentation](https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/getting-started/simple-mode/#postgresqls-sort-option) references RobDil's answer below, which seems like a solution with rougher edges than one might think after 9 years.

Answer (score 1):

10 months, maybe too late!!

This solved my problem with posgresql

```
sort_link @search, 'lowercase(name)', "Name"
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work when working with an association, for example **sort_link @search, 'lowercase(patient.last_name)', "Name"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to hd1 who posted the approach above.
I am posting the actual code here - it's not ideal, since it seems like a wordy workaround.
Still open to cleaner suggestions.

```
def index
  @search = Vendor.search(params[:q])
  @vendors = @search.result

  if params[:q].present?
    params[:q].each do |k, v| 
      if v == 'name asc'
        @vendors = @search.result.sort { |p1, p2| p1.name.downcase <=> p2.name.downcase }
      elsif v == 'name desc'
        @vendors = @search.result.sort { |p2, p1| p1.name.downcase <=> p2.name.downcase }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

RobDil's answer from 2016 is now recognized as the best way to do this for multiple columns on a model in the [ransack documentation](https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/getting-started/simple-mode/#case-insensitive-sorting-in-postgresql). But if you want to do this for just one column, you can do it with a custom ransacker:

```
class Vendor < ApplicationRecord

  ransacker :name, type: :string do
    Arel.sql("lower(vendors.name)")
  end

end
```

Note that there are a couple nuances now vs. mutexkid's 2014 answer:

- you must specify the table name when using the Arel.sql() syntax
- you can simply override the "name" default ransacker, rather than creating a separate name_case_insensitive one. Searching still works fine. No need to change sort links in your views.

If you do want to create a separate name_case_insensitive ransacker, you will need to add "name_case_insensitive" to your ransackable_attributes for the Vendor object.

Credit to RobDil and mutexkid for the original answers, just thought I'd add this here as figuring out the syntax specifics took me way too long a decade after they were published.